# Exception "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction" using TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, msdtc

We have a web service on server #1 and a database on server #2.
Web service uses transaction scope to produce distributed transaction. Everything is correct.

And we have another database on server #3. We had some problems with this server and we reinstalled operation system and software. We configured MSDTC and tried to use web service from server #1 to communicate with database on this server.
And now after first select statement within transaction scope we get: `The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction`. This exception falls in every web service request if it is using transaction scope.
Server #2 and Server #3 is almost similar. The difference can be only in settings.
.NET framework 3.5  SP1 installed and SQL Server SP3 on all servers.

**Full stacktrace:**

> System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction
>   tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification
>   promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction) в
>   System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification
>   promotableSinglePhaseNotification) в 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
>   t в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction t в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction
>   transaction) в
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction
>   transaction) в 
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject) в
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) в
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() в 
>   NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() в
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenConnection()

I searched this message but didn't found any appropriate solution.
So what settings should I check and what exactly should I do to fix it?

Comment: What OS and how exactly did you configure MSDTC?

Comment: What form of the TransactionScope()  constructor are you using?

Comment: Hi Lanfear,

Did you solve this problem? We are getting same error on test environment. Same code on Dev environment works fine.

Answer (score 31):

Lanfear, I have come across the same error message and I found a solution.  Your situation may be different, but I hope that the following knowledge will be useful to you.

`System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status` will return the status of the current transaction.

In each case where an exception is thrown with the message `The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction`, when I step thru with the debugger, I see that the status is "Aborted" before the exception is thrown.

In my case, the problem was caused by nesting two transactions inside each other and mistakenly aborting both when I wanted to abort only one.  Apparently, if you use the `TransactionScope` default constructor `New TransactionScope()` with two nested transactions, aborting the inner transaction aborts the outer transaction as well.  The solution is to use the Constructor `New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)`  Using this constructor, the inner transaction will be a new transaction and aborting it will not abort the outer transaction.

This solved my issue.

Comment: System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status helped me pinpoint exactly when the transaction was being aborted.

Comment: @AdamMarshall real world sample using `TransactionInformation.Status`?

Answer (score 5):

Enabling the Distributed Transaction Coordinator solved the issue for me (this was done on both machines: the one that has the web service and the one that has the database. Not sure though if it is needed for the web service).

I followed the steps described here to enable the DTC and to add an exception to the Windows Firewall: [Enable Network DTC Access for Windows Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753510%28WS.10%29.aspx)